# Can two different Schrödinger equations have the same wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Is it possible for two Schrödinger equations describing different systems to have the same wavefunction? And if that is the case, why or why not?

Comment: It will depend on how broad your definition of a  "Schordinger equation" is, but for systems of electrons the answer is essentially no. The [1st Hohenberg-Kohn Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory#Hohenberg.E2.80.93Kohn_theorems) states that given the ground state electron density the potential is fixed up to a constant.

Comment: When you say "different" equations. Do you simply mean that the potential is different?

Comment: @MikaelFremling The potential is different.

Comment: @BySymmetry I thought that the 1st Hohenberg-Kohn Theorem said that the density is as good as the wavefunction in describing the system. Also, isn't it just for ground states?

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO The Hohenberg-Kohn Theorem states thats we can deduce the Hamiltonian from the ground state elctron density. Since from the Hamiltonian we can, in principle, find the energy eigenstate wavefunctions, so the ground state electron density contains as much information as the wavefunctions. I had, however, forgotten about the restriction to the ground state. I don't know whether you can have two Hamiltonian with the same wavefunction for "different" eigenstates. A hand wavy node counting argument suggests that you might be able to generalise the result, at least in a special case

Comment: @By Symmetry This is clearly false, knowing a single vector from an operators spectrum is not sufficient to define the operator.

Comment: @Comptonscattering the Hohenberg-kohn Theorem is limited to Electronic Hamiltonians of the form $\frac{1}{2m}p^2+v(x)$. This is why I originally asked what was meant by a Shrouding equation. I.e. All you need to determine is the potential.

Comment: Strictly speaking free particles equations in different domains describe different systems and the plane waves are solutions of all of them (although that's a trivial case).

Comment: To be clear, you mean the time-independent Schrödinger equation, or the time-dependent version? If the time-dependent one, do you mean at a single time or at all times? If by "wavefunction" you mean specifically "eigenfunction", you should make that explicit.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I wasn't aware about that when I asked the question. But it appears that the Hohenberg-Kohn theorem is a special case. I would think that for the time dependent case, the answer would be a yes for all times. I am not sure for a single time, however.

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO You have yet to clarify: is this for the TISE, the TDSE, or both?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty For both then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is very broadly posed, so there's a bunch of different ways to interpret it, and each of them can give a different answer.

- **Can two different Hamiltonians share an eigenfunction?**

  **Yes.** The answer by ComptonScattering gives an example in finite dimensions; if you want something closer to the usual three-dimensional quantum mechanics of a massive particle, there's even more examples (because the Hilbert space is much bigger).

  For something concrete, you can try the hydrogenic Hamiltonian $\hat H_0$ and $$\hat H = \hat H_0 + f(\hat r) \, \hat L{}^2,$$ where $f(r)\geq0$ is a non-negative function of the radius. Here the ground state will be the same for both (as will all the $\ell=0$ states) but $\ell\neq 0$ states will differ.
- **Can two different Hamiltonians share *all* their eigenfunctions?**

  **Yes.** For a simple example, take any Hamiltonian $\hat H_1 = \hat H$ that is not the identity operator, and compare it with $\hat H_2 = \hat H{}^2$. Then every eigenfunction of $\hat H_1$ will be an eigenfunction of $\hat H_2$ (though the converse of that is not necessarily true), but the eigenvalues will in general differ.
- **Can two different Hamiltonians share *all* their eigenfunctions *and* the eigenvalues?**

  **No.** This is because you can express the Hamiltonian as a function  of the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. In Dirac notation, that reads $$\hat H = \sum_n E_n |n⟩⟨n|.$$
- **Can two different Hamiltonians share at least one solution of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation, for all times?**

  **Yes.** The eigenfunction examples of the first point above are a suitable example.
- **Can two different Hamiltonians share an arbitrary wavefunction in their solutions of the Schrödinger equation, at least for a single time $t_0$?**

  **Yes.** Easy: set up some arbitrary wavefunction $\psi(t_0)$, and let it run under your two arbitrary Hamiltonians $\hat H_1$ and $\hat H_2$. They'll typically take $\psi(t_0)$ in arbitrary, different directions, but hey, the solutions matched at time $t_0$.
- **Can two different Hamiltonians share solutions of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for all times and for arbitrary initial conditions?**

  **No.** Take an arbitrary wavefunction $\psi_0$, and use that as the initial condition $\psi(t_0) = \psi_0$ for the Schrödinger equation under arbitrary $\hat H_1$ and $\hat H_2$. By assumption, both solutions are equal, and in particular their time derivatives at $t_0$ are also equal. (In fact, that is all you need: agreement of the wavefunction and its time derivative, for arbitrary initial conditions.) This then implies that $$\hat H_1 \psi_0 = i\hbar \partial_t \psi(t_0) = \hat H_2 \psi_0,$$ i.e. that $\hat H_1$ and $\hat H_2$ agree on your arbitrary initial condition $\psi_0$. This then means that they must agree as operators.

As a final note, please note the huge number of questions that folded into your original query, because of its imprecise phrasing, and use it to learn the importance of providing sharp, well-defined questions.

Comment: @ComptonScattering What does that even mean? You know better than the OP in terms of asking ill-defined questions.

Comment: For completeness it is worth mentioning that if there is  gauge freedom in your system, there are families of different Hamiltonians related by gauge transformations which lead to the the same evolution of all observable quantities, even though the wavefunctions are different.

Comment: @ComptonScattering Yes and no. The experimental quantities (matrix elements of operators) do stay constant, but the operators that correspond to physical quantities also change. (It's also worth noting that nothing there is new to quantum mechanics, either - just about everything there is already present in the hamiltonian classical mechanics to begin with.) At present that's too nebulous to include in this answer, and it would only serve to further confuse the OP.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty How come the first section in your answer (Hydrogenic atom) does not contradict the Hohenberg-kohn Theorem?

Comment: @proton Why would it? The added operator is not a function of position (it includes position derivatives via the angular momentum operator). This answer is three years old and its claims can be directly verified without recourse to external theorems. If you have direct concerns about the claims here, then by all means express them, but if you have questions about the relationship to external features of the theory, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting the question as "Can two different time independent Schrodinger equations have the same solution", or "... same ground state solution".

Then yes by construction. Let $| \psi_i \rangle$, $i = 1,2,3$ be three orthogonal wavefunctions.

We can construct two Hamiltonians

$$H_a = E_1 | \psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1 | + E_2 | \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2 | + E_3 | \psi_3 \rangle \langle \psi_3 |$$

and

$$H_b = E_1 | \psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1 | + \frac{E_2}{2} \left( | \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2 | + | \psi_3 \rangle \langle \psi_3 | + | \psi_3 \rangle \langle \psi_2 | + | \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_3 |  \right) + \frac{E_3}{2} \left( | \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2 | + | \psi_3 \rangle \langle \psi_3 | - | \psi_3 \rangle \langle \psi_2 | - | \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_3 |  \right)$$

have the same ground state for $E_1<E_2,E_3,0$ (and the same spectra).

Comment: If we don't care about locality of the Hamiltonian and treat it simply as a matrix on some abstract Hilbert space then your answer is correct. If we care about locality in some predetermined  coordinate representation then your construction will be unsuccessful.

Comment: Agreed. Though we can make other constructions if we have more stringent requirements. Generally any perturbation to the Hamiltonian that commutes with the ground state projector will produce a new Hamiltonian with the same ground state.

Comment: @OON No, it's pretty easy to cook similar examples in the position representation. Consider e.g. the hydrogenic hamiltonian $\hat H_0$, and its perturbation to $$\hat H = \hat H_0 +f(\hat r)\hat L^2,$$ where $f(r)\geq 0$ throughout, which can be quite different but which share the same ground state.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I don't say that it's impossible, of course not. I say that if you want to preserve locality it's much less simple than what this answer suggests.

Comment: @OON well, your comment does specifically say that it is impossible. And frankly, there's so much room in Hilbert space that arguing about such details is pretty pointless - finding such examples is plenty simple.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Very good. Can you easily find two local Hamiltonians with *only* difference being that rotation is done for *two* eigenstates and all other eigenstates are not changed?

Comment: @OON That's nowhere near what the question asked.